# W3 service stops, but w3wp.exe are still running for a number of seconds

Tags: iis

I stopped the World Wide Web Publishing Service - normally this service won't stop until all of the w3wp.exe processes shut down.  But I am now seeing a strange behavior where the service actually stops quickly -- but the w3wp.exe is still there, and those processes end after a number of seconds (10-15 seconds?)  Did something change in the behavior of IIS?

Answer (score 0):

The default ShutdownTimeLimit value is 90 seconds. application pool needs time to fully shut down, as any requests currently processing when the shutdown is initiated and needs to be given a certain amount of time to complete.

if it takes too long time to shut down then you could troubleshoot the application pool by capturing a memory dump of the w3wp.exe process in which the application pool is running, when the shutdown problem is occurring.

For more information on capturing memory dumps of IIS processes, see [Debug Diagnostics Tool v1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/help/2580960) is now available.

Comment: It's not taking too long to shut down, but the behavior changed.  Stopping the W3 service would always wait until all the application pools shut down -- and then possibly the service timeout would occur if it took too long.  But now I am seeing the service stop completely within a few seconds, although the w3wp.exe processes are still running for maybe 10 seconds more.

Comment: @BrianClink which application you are running on the IIS? is it a long-running application? you could try this command `taskkill /IM w3wp.exe /F` This tells taskkill to force terminate the process since it may be in use, stalled, or otherwise unable to terminate on request.

Comment: Jalpa, I think you missed the original intent of the question - I am asking about a behavior change in IIS, that the IIS service stopped but w3wp.exe processes are still running, which is different behavior than what my years of experience with IIS has ingrained in me.  Usually W3 service will wait until all the w3wp.exe processes shut down - however long that takes, before the W3 service appears as stopped.  I am not concerned about the application, I am concerned about the change in IIS behavior.